# view .doc, .docx, .rtf, .ppt file in iphone using Webview

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

I want to view .doc, .docx, .rtf, .ppt file in iphone.

But I guess something is going wrong at my side and its not working for the above formats but my code is working fine for .txt and .pdf files.

I have the read the document regarding Webview it states it supports viewing of the above document.

below is my snippet for .doc

```
[webView loadData:requestData MIMEType:@"application/msword" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

for .ppt I am using MIME type as `"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"`

Note: If I am making MIME type as "text/html" for .doc/.rtf then it displays some garbage data  So I think there is something missing in MIME type from my side.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Waiting for your reply.

**Update**:........

It seems there is some issue with NSData for opening these type of file formats.
My data is encrypted so I cannot use 
**requestWithURL** directly and other thing is I need to pass credentials to get the file and the credentials doesnt work proplerly if I save the credentials using

```
[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential
                                        forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
```

and then make the request using below

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]] ]
```

Is there any way I can use NSData for the above formats so that I can make async call and pass my credentials and then decrypt the data and show it in WebView.

Comment: Please refer to this set of mime types (works for pptx) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of those formats (docx) are supported.  This looks like the [official word](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html).  In the example Apple does not specify a mime type.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764709/iphone-uiwebview-loaddata-does-not-work-with-certain-types-excel-msword-ppt) suggests that you must use an NSURLRequest instead of loadData.

Edit:

As far as I have seen, you cannot directly pass data to loadData for these types.

The easy work around is to write to a temporary file.  You can delete it in webViewDidFinishLoad or, technically, as soon as the the file has been opened.

The hard work around is to use NSURLCache.  You should be able to implement a custom NSURLCache and have WebKit use it via setSharedURLCache.  Your cache would basically know how to get your local encrypted files and pretend that they are cached.  I have not tried this, but I think it is your best bet.  This approach may be blocked just like loadData is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
By data is encrypted so it seems I cannot use NSURLRequest directly. IS there any way I can use NSData to open my .doc, .ppt files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have the tried the first method its working.
Working on second method

Answer (score 5):

Try using a **QuickLook** Framework which is an amazing feature given by Apple. If you have seen this that when you select ANY FILE on MAC System and click SPACE BAR then you will a quick preview of your file it may be any thing... *.pdf, *.doc, *.docx or any thing... Even if you have not installed those softwares for same files you will get a PREVIEW for those files...

**QuickLook** framework also gives same functionality... Please go through some of the links for the same..

- http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/2011/02/quick-look-for-ios_21.html
- https://github.com/rob-brown/Demos
- https://github.com/rob-brown/RBFilePreviewer
- http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/2011/02/quick-look-for-ios_21.html
- (Recommended..) http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html

Comment: i know you want to use WebView but this is also best for any files... :)

Comment: I cannot open `.docx` files using `Quick Look Framework`. My files are downloaded to Documents directory.

Answer (score 3):

You need to supply something to baseURL:. For example:

```
[webView loadData:requestData MIMEType:@"application/msword" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/"]];
```

Works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it on an iPhone instead of Simulator