# What is a correct MIME type for .docx, .pptx, etc.?

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint, mime-types

For older *.doc documents, this was enough:

```
header("Content-Type: application/msword");
```

What MIME type should I use for new .docx documents? Also, for pptx and xlsx documents?

Comment: If you using linux,  you can make use of this command `file -bi YOUR_FILE`

Comment: @ajreal that doesn't provide the MIME type. The output for a jpg with that command would look like `JPEG image data, EXIF standard`

Comment: @wmarbut An alternative name for the `-i` flag is `--mime`.

Comment: @wmarbut Seems to provide the mime type to me. Tried it with a jpeg and got: `image/jpeg; charset=binary`, where `image/jpeg` is the mime type.

Comment: you may have look on them here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx

Comment: ``/usr/bin/file`` is identifying ``ppt`` incorrectly as ``application/vnd.ms-office``. (Linux and Mac) I haven't found why this is and we need to override for this case.

Answer (score 3070, accepted):

Here are the correct Microsoft Office MIME types for HTTP content streaming:

```
Extension MIME Type
.doc      application/msword
.dot      application/msword

.docx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.docm     application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.dotm     application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12

.xls      application/vnd.ms-excel
.xlt      application/vnd.ms-excel
.xla      application/vnd.ms-excel

.xlsx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
.xlsm     application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
.xltm     application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
.xlam     application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
.xlsb     application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12

.ppt      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pot      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pps      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.ppa      application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.pptx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.potx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppsx     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.ppam     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
.pptm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
.potm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
.ppsm     application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12

.mdb      application/vnd.ms-access
```

For further details check out this [TechNet article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2007-resource-kit/ee309278%28v=office.12%29) and this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160215155254/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx).

Comment: This is maybe a little old, I use application/vnd.ms-excel for .xlsx

Comment: application/vnd.ms-excel is specifically for .xls files.  the ability for it to work with .xlsx depends on the client software in use.

Comment: I have seen `Application/vnd.ms-word` as a content-type being returned by Microsoft IIS servers for older `.doc` files. Even if that isn't proper, you should try to handle it if you're relying on the content-type when downloading.

Comment: For "Word 2003 XML" format, which has the .xml extension and is still very useful for creating dynamic word documents server-side, the "application/msword" MIME Type seems to work fine.

Comment: If one day there is a tutorial with example answers on how to answer, I would put this answer there.

Comment: Since no one else has said it: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" - was that really necessary?!

Comment: If you use the `application/vnd.ms-excel` MIME type and return a file with an `.xls` extension in Firefox, when you click on "Open with" in the dialog, Firefox will automatically append an `.xls` extension to the end of the file, which will then make MS Excel display a warning about the file possibly not being secure (which will probably confuse your users).

Comment: @DanielGray: The .xls extension is the correct one for that mime type. Is the original extension of your file correct? My guess is that the extension should be .xlsx and the mime type should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean if you return the `application/vnd.ms-excel` MIME type and return a file with an `.xlsx` extension, Firefox will automatically append the `.xls` extension, which causes the warning popup.

Comment: For reference : [IANA Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: Just look at [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for the [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)

Comment: For opening Excel files on iPad Safari & Chrome on iOS (CriOS) both require that the .xlsx file extension is mapped to this MIME type: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. If it's incorrectly mapped - where the .xls file extension's MIME type: `application/vnd.ms-excel` is used for .xlsx files - then both browsers will both throw errors & prevent the files from opening in new tabs. Safari uses a "View" link to open the Excel file in a new tab. Chrome simply opens Excel files in new tabs.

Comment: In the wild I also saw the MIME type `application/oleobject` for an `.ods` spreadsheet file attached to an email.

Answer (score 63):

Here is an (almost) complete file extensions's MIME in a JSON format.
You can do these examples: `MIME["ppt"]`, `MIME["docx"]`, etc

```json
{
    "x3d": "application/vnd.hzn-3d-crossword",
    "3gp": "video/3gpp",
    "3g2": "video/3gpp2",
    "mseq": "application/vnd.mseq",
    "pwn": "application/vnd.3m.post-it-notes",
    "plb": "application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-large",
    "psb": "application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-small",
    "pvb": "application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-var",
    "tcap": "application/vnd.3gpp2.tcap",
    "7z": "application/x-7z-compressed",
    "abw": "application/x-abiword",
    "ace": "application/x-ace-compressed",
    "acc": "application/vnd.americandynamics.acc",
    "acu": "application/vnd.acucobol",
    "atc": "application/vnd.acucorp",
    "adp": "audio/adpcm",
    "aab": "application/x-authorware-bin",
    "aam": "application/x-authorware-map",
    "aas": "application/x-authorware-seg",
    "air": "application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip",
    "swf": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
    "fxp": "application/vnd.adobe.fxp",
    "pdf": "application/pdf",
    "ppd": "application/vnd.cups-ppd",
    "dir": "application/x-director",
    "xdp": "application/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml",
    "xfdf": "application/vnd.adobe.xfdf",
    "aac": "audio/x-aac",
    "ahead": "application/vnd.ahead.space",
    "azf": "application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azf",
    "azs": "application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azs",
    "azw": "application/vnd.amazon.ebook",
    "ami": "application/vnd.amiga.ami",
    "N/A": "application/andrew-inset",
    "apk": "application/vnd.android.package-archive",
    "cii": "application/vnd.anser-web-certificate-issue-initiation",
    "fti": "application/vnd.anser-web-funds-transfer-initiation",
    "atx": "application/vnd.antix.game-component",
    "dmg": "application/x-apple-diskimage",
    "mpkg": "application/vnd.apple.installer+xml",
    "aw": "application/applixware",
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "les": "application/vnd.hhe.lesson-player",
    "swi": "application/vnd.aristanetworks.swi",
    "s": "text/x-asm",
    "atomcat": "application/atomcat+xml",
    "atomsvc": "application/atomsvc+xml",
    "atom": "application/atom+xml",
    "ac": "application/pkix-attr-cert",
    "aif": "audio/x-aiff",
    "avi": "video/x-msvideo",
    "aep": "application/vnd.audiograph",
    "dxf": "image/vnd.dxf",
    "dwf": "model/vnd.dwf",
    "par": "text/plain-bas",
    "bcpio": "application/x-bcpio",
    "bin": "application/octet-stream",
    "bmp": "image/bmp",
    "torrent": "application/x-bittorrent",
    "cod": "application/vnd.rim.cod",
    "mpm": "application/vnd.blueice.multipass",
    "bmi": "application/vnd.bmi",
    "sh": "application/x-sh",
    "btif": "image/prs.btif",
    "rep": "application/vnd.businessobjects",
    "bz": "application/x-bzip",
    "bz2": "application/x-bzip2",
    "csh": "application/x-csh",
    "c": "text/x-c",
    "cdxml": "application/vnd.chemdraw+xml",
    "css": "text/css",
    "cdx": "chemical/x-cdx",
    "cml": "chemical/x-cml",
    "csml": "chemical/x-csml",
    "cdbcmsg": "application/vnd.contact.cmsg",
    "cla": "application/vnd.claymore",
    "c4g": "application/vnd.clonk.c4group",
    "sub": "image/vnd.dvb.subtitle",
    "cdmia": "application/cdmi-capability",
    "cdmic": "application/cdmi-container",
    "cdmid": "application/cdmi-domain",
    "cdmio": "application/cdmi-object",
    "cdmiq": "application/cdmi-queue",
    "c11amc": "application/vnd.cluetrust.cartomobile-config",
    "c11amz": "application/vnd.cluetrust.cartomobile-config-pkg",
    "ras": "image/x-cmu-raster",
    "dae": "model/vnd.collada+xml",
    "csv": "text/csv",
    "cpt": "application/mac-compactpro",
    "wmlc": "application/vnd.wap.wmlc",
    "cgm": "image/cgm",
    "ice": "x-conference/x-cooltalk",
    "cmx": "image/x-cmx",
    "xar": "application/vnd.xara",
    "cmc": "application/vnd.cosmocaller",
    "cpio": "application/x-cpio",
    "clkx": "application/vnd.crick.clicker",
    "clkk": "application/vnd.crick.clicker.keyboard",
    "clkp": "application/vnd.crick.clicker.palette",
    "clkt": "application/vnd.crick.clicker.template",
    "clkw": "application/vnd.crick.clicker.wordbank",
    "wbs": "application/vnd.criticaltools.wbs+xml",
    "cryptonote": "application/vnd.rig.cryptonote",
    "cif": "chemical/x-cif",
    "cmdf": "chemical/x-cmdf",
    "cu": "application/cu-seeme",
    "cww": "application/prs.cww",
    "curl": "text/vnd.curl",
    "dcurl": "text/vnd.curl.dcurl",
    "mcurl": "text/vnd.curl.mcurl",
    "scurl": "text/vnd.curl.scurl",
    "car": "application/vnd.curl.car",
    "pcurl": "application/vnd.curl.pcurl",
    "cmp": "application/vnd.yellowriver-custom-menu",
    "dssc": "application/dssc+der",
    "xdssc": "application/dssc+xml",
    "deb": "application/x-debian-package",
    "uva": "audio/vnd.dece.audio",
    "uvi": "image/vnd.dece.graphic",
    "uvh": "video/vnd.dece.hd",
    "uvm": "video/vnd.dece.mobile",
    "uvu": "video/vnd.uvvu.mp4",
    "uvp": "video/vnd.dece.pd",
    "uvs": "video/vnd.dece.sd",
    "uvv": "video/vnd.dece.video",
    "dvi": "application/x-dvi",
    "seed": "application/vnd.fdsn.seed",
    "dtb": "application/x-dtbook+xml",
    "res": "application/x-dtbresource+xml",
    "ait": "application/vnd.dvb.ait",
    "svc": "application/vnd.dvb.service",
    "eol": "audio/vnd.digital-winds",
    "djvu": "image/vnd.djvu",
    "dtd": "application/xml-dtd",
    "mlp": "application/vnd.dolby.mlp",
    "wad": "application/x-doom",
    "dpg": "application/vnd.dpgraph",
    "dra": "audio/vnd.dra",
    "dfac": "application/vnd.dreamfactory",
    "dts": "audio/vnd.dts",
    "dtshd": "audio/vnd.dts.hd",
    "dwg": "image/vnd.dwg",
    "geo": "application/vnd.dynageo",
    "es": "application/ecmascript",
    "mag": "application/vnd.ecowin.chart",
    "mmr": "image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-mmr",
    "rlc": "image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-rlc",
    "exi": "application/exi",
    "mgz": "application/vnd.proteus.magazine",
    "epub": "application/epub+zip",
    "eml": "message/rfc822",
    "nml": "application/vnd.enliven",
    "xpr": "application/vnd.is-xpr",
    "xif": "image/vnd.xiff",
    "xfdl": "application/vnd.xfdl",
    "emma": "application/emma+xml",
    "ez2": "application/vnd.ezpix-album",
    "ez3": "application/vnd.ezpix-package",
    "fst": "image/vnd.fst",
    "fvt": "video/vnd.fvt",
    "fbs": "image/vnd.fastbidsheet",
    "fe_launch": "application/vnd.denovo.fcselayout-link",
    "f4v": "video/x-f4v",
    "flv": "video/x-flv",
    "fpx": "image/vnd.fpx",
    "npx": "image/vnd.net-fpx",
    "flx": "text/vnd.fmi.flexstor",
    "fli": "video/x-fli",
    "ftc": "application/vnd.fluxtime.clip",
    "fdf": "application/vnd.fdf",
    "f": "text/x-fortran",
    "mif": "application/vnd.mif",
    "fm": "application/vnd.framemaker",
    "fh": "image/x-freehand",
    "fsc": "application/vnd.fsc.weblaunch",
    "fnc": "application/vnd.frogans.fnc",
    "ltf": "application/vnd.frogans.ltf",
    "ddd": "application/vnd.fujixerox.ddd",
    "xdw": "application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks",
    "xbd": "application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks.binder",
    "oas": "application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys",
    "oa2": "application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys2",
    "oa3": "application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys3",
    "fg5": "application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysgp",
    "bh2": "application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysprs",
    "spl": "application/x-futuresplash",
    "fzs": "application/vnd.fuzzysheet",
    "g3": "image/g3fax",
    "gmx": "application/vnd.gmx",
    "gtw": "model/vnd.gtw",
    "txd": "application/vnd.genomatix.tuxedo",
    "ggb": "application/vnd.geogebra.file",
    "ggt": "application/vnd.geogebra.tool",
    "gdl": "model/vnd.gdl",
    "gex": "application/vnd.geometry-explorer",
    "gxt": "application/vnd.geonext",
    "g2w": "application/vnd.geoplan",
    "g3w": "application/vnd.geospace",
    "gsf": "application/x-font-ghostscript",
    "bdf": "application/x-font-bdf",
    "gtar": "application/x-gtar",
    "texinfo": "application/x-texinfo",
    "gnumeric": "application/x-gnumeric",
    "kml": "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
    "kmz": "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz",
    "gqf": "application/vnd.grafeq",
    "gif": "image/gif",
    "gv": "text/vnd.graphviz",
    "gac": "application/vnd.groove-account",
    "ghf": "application/vnd.groove-help",
    "gim": "application/vnd.groove-identity-message",
    "grv": "application/vnd.groove-injector",
    "gtm": "application/vnd.groove-tool-message",
    "tpl": "application/vnd.groove-tool-template",
    "vcg": "application/vnd.groove-vcard",
    "h261": "video/h261",
    "h263": "video/h263",
    "h264": "video/h264",
    "hpid": "application/vnd.hp-hpid",
    "hps": "application/vnd.hp-hps",
    "hdf": "application/x-hdf",
    "rip": "audio/vnd.rip",
    "hbci": "application/vnd.hbci",
    "jlt": "application/vnd.hp-jlyt",
    "pcl": "application/vnd.hp-pcl",
    "hpgl": "application/vnd.hp-hpgl",
    "hvs": "application/vnd.yamaha.hv-script",
    "hvd": "application/vnd.yamaha.hv-dic",
    "hvp": "application/vnd.yamaha.hv-voice",
    "sfd-hdstx": "application/vnd.hydrostatix.sof-data",
    "stk": "application/hyperstudio",
    "hal": "application/vnd.hal+xml",
    "html": "text/html",
    "irm": "application/vnd.ibm.rights-management",
    "sc": "application/vnd.ibm.secure-container",
    "ics": "text/calendar",
    "icc": "application/vnd.iccprofile",
    "ico": "image/x-icon",
    "igl": "application/vnd.igloader",
    "ief": "image/ief",
    "ivp": "application/vnd.immervision-ivp",
    "ivu": "application/vnd.immervision-ivu",
    "rif": "application/reginfo+xml",
    "3dml": "text/vnd.in3d.3dml",
    "spot": "text/vnd.in3d.spot",
    "igs": "model/iges",
    "i2g": "application/vnd.intergeo",
    "cdy": "application/vnd.cinderella",
    "xpw": "application/vnd.intercon.formnet",
    "fcs": "application/vnd.isac.fcs",
    "ipfix": "application/ipfix",
    "cer": "application/pkix-cert",
    "pki": "application/pkixcmp",
    "crl": "application/pkix-crl",
    "pkipath": "application/pkix-pkipath",
    "igm": "application/vnd.insors.igm",
    "rcprofile": "application/vnd.ipunplugged.rcprofile",
    "irp": "application/vnd.irepository.package+xml",
    "jad": "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor",
    "jar": "application/java-archive",
    "class": "application/java-vm",
    "jnlp": "application/x-java-jnlp-file",
    "ser": "application/java-serialized-object",
    "java": "text/x-java-source,java",
    "js": "application/javascript",
    "json": "application/json",
    "joda": "application/vnd.joost.joda-archive",
    "jpm": "video/jpm",
    "jpeg": "image/x-citrix-jpeg",
    "jpg": "image/x-citrix-jpeg",
    "pjpeg": "image/pjpeg",
    "jpgv": "video/jpeg",
    "ktz": "application/vnd.kahootz",
    "mmd": "application/vnd.chipnuts.karaoke-mmd",
    "karbon": "application/vnd.kde.karbon",
    "chrt": "application/vnd.kde.kchart",
    "kfo": "application/vnd.kde.kformula",
    "flw": "application/vnd.kde.kivio",
    "kon": "application/vnd.kde.kontour",
    "kpr": "application/vnd.kde.kpresenter",
    "ksp": "application/vnd.kde.kspread",
    "kwd": "application/vnd.kde.kword",
    "htke": "application/vnd.kenameaapp",
    "kia": "application/vnd.kidspiration",
    "kne": "application/vnd.kinar",
    "sse": "application/vnd.kodak-descriptor",
    "lasxml": "application/vnd.las.las+xml",
    "latex": "application/x-latex",
    "lbd": "application/vnd.llamagraphics.life-balance.desktop",
    "lbe": "application/vnd.llamagraphics.life-balance.exchange+xml",
    "jam": "application/vnd.jam",
    "123": "application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3",
    "apr": "application/vnd.lotus-approach",
    "pre": "application/vnd.lotus-freelance",
    "nsf": "application/vnd.lotus-notes",
    "org": "application/vnd.lotus-organizer",
    "scm": "application/vnd.lotus-screencam",
    "lwp": "application/vnd.lotus-wordpro",
    "lvp": "audio/vnd.lucent.voice",
    "m3u": "audio/x-mpegurl",
    "m4v": "video/x-m4v",
    "hqx": "application/mac-binhex40",
    "portpkg": "application/vnd.macports.portpkg",
    "mgp": "application/vnd.osgeo.mapguide.package",
    "mrc": "application/marc",
    "mrcx": "application/marcxml+xml",
    "mxf": "application/mxf",
    "nbp": "application/vnd.wolfram.player",
    "ma": "application/mathematica",
    "mathml": "application/mathml+xml",
    "mbox": "application/mbox",
    "mc1": "application/vnd.medcalcdata",
    "mscml": "application/mediaservercontrol+xml",
    "cdkey": "application/vnd.mediastation.cdkey",
    "mwf": "application/vnd.mfer",
    "mfm": "application/vnd.mfmp",
    "msh": "model/mesh",
    "mads": "application/mads+xml",
    "mets": "application/mets+xml",
    "mods": "application/mods+xml",
    "meta4": "application/metalink4+xml",
    "mcd": "application/vnd.mcd",
    "flo": "application/vnd.micrografx.flo",
    "igx": "application/vnd.micrografx.igx",
    "es3": "application/vnd.eszigno3+xml",
    "mdb": "application/x-msaccess",
    "asf": "video/x-ms-asf",
    "exe": "application/x-msdownload",
    "cil": "application/vnd.ms-artgalry",
    "cab": "application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed",
    "ims": "application/vnd.ms-ims",
    "application": "application/x-ms-application",
    "clp": "application/x-msclip",
    "mdi": "image/vnd.ms-modi",
    "eot": "application/vnd.ms-fontobject",
    "xls": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xlam": "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12",
    "xlsb": "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12",
    "xltm": "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12",
    "xlsm": "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12",
    "chm": "application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp",
    "crd": "application/x-mscardfile",
    "lrm": "application/vnd.ms-lrm",
    "mvb": "application/x-msmediaview",
    "mny": "application/x-msmoney",
    "pptx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
    "sldx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide",
    "ppsx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow",
    "potx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template",
    "xlsx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "xltx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template",
    "docx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "dotx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",
    "obd": "application/x-msbinder",
    "thmx": "application/vnd.ms-officetheme",
    "onetoc": "application/onenote",
    "pya": "audio/vnd.ms-playready.media.pya",
    "pyv": "video/vnd.ms-playready.media.pyv",
    "ppt": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "ppam": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroenabled.12",
    "sldm": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroenabled.12",
    "pptm": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12",
    "ppsm": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12",
    "potm": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12",
    "mpp": "application/vnd.ms-project",
    "pub": "application/x-mspublisher",
    "scd": "application/x-msschedule",
    "xap": "application/x-silverlight-app",
    "stl": "application/vnd.ms-pki.stl",
    "cat": "application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat",
    "vsd": "application/vnd.visio",
    "vsdx": "application/vnd.visio2013",
    "wm": "video/x-ms-wm",
    "wma": "audio/x-ms-wma",
    "wax": "audio/x-ms-wax",
    "wmx": "video/x-ms-wmx",
    "wmd": "application/x-ms-wmd",
    "wpl": "application/vnd.ms-wpl",
    "wmz": "application/x-ms-wmz",
    "wmv": "video/x-ms-wmv",
    "wvx": "video/x-ms-wvx",
    "wmf": "application/x-msmetafile",
    "trm": "application/x-msterminal",
    "doc": "application/msword",
    "docm": "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12",
    "dotm": "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12",
    "wri": "application/x-mswrite",
    "wps": "application/vnd.ms-works",
    "xbap": "application/x-ms-xbap",
    "xps": "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument",
    "mid": "audio/midi",
    "mpy": "application/vnd.ibm.minipay",
    "afp": "application/vnd.ibm.modcap",
    "rms": "application/vnd.jcp.javame.midlet-rms",
    "tmo": "application/vnd.tmobile-livetv",
    "prc": "application/x-mobipocket-ebook",
    "mbk": "application/vnd.mobius.mbk",
    "dis": "application/vnd.mobius.dis",
    "plc": "application/vnd.mobius.plc",
    "mqy": "application/vnd.mobius.mqy",
    "msl": "application/vnd.mobius.msl",
    "txf": "application/vnd.mobius.txf",
    "daf": "application/vnd.mobius.daf",
    "fly": "text/vnd.fly",
    "mpc": "application/vnd.mophun.certificate",
    "mpn": "application/vnd.mophun.application",
    "mj2": "video/mj2",
    "mpga": "audio/mpeg",
    "mxu": "video/vnd.mpegurl",
    "mpeg": "video/mpeg",
    "m21": "application/mp21",
    "mp4a": "audio/mp4",
    "mp4": "video/mp4",
    "m3u8": "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl",
    "mus": "application/vnd.musician",
    "msty": "application/vnd.muvee.style",
    "mxml": "application/xv+xml",
    "ngdat": "application/vnd.nokia.n-gage.data",
    "n-gage": "application/vnd.nokia.n-gage.symbian.install",
    "ncx": "application/x-dtbncx+xml",
    "nc": "application/x-netcdf",
    "nlu": "application/vnd.neurolanguage.nlu",
    "dna": "application/vnd.dna",
    "nnd": "application/vnd.noblenet-directory",
    "nns": "application/vnd.noblenet-sealer",
    "nnw": "application/vnd.noblenet-web",
    "rpst": "application/vnd.nokia.radio-preset",
    "rpss": "application/vnd.nokia.radio-presets",
    "n3": "text/n3",
    "edm": "application/vnd.novadigm.edm",
    "edx": "application/vnd.novadigm.edx",
    "ext": "application/vnd.novadigm.ext",
    "gph": "application/vnd.flographit",
    "ecelp4800": "audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp4800",
    "ecelp7470": "audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp7470",
    "ecelp9600": "audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp9600",
    "oda": "application/oda",
    "ogx": "application/ogg",
    "oga": "audio/ogg",
    "ogv": "video/ogg",
    "dd2": "application/vnd.oma.dd2+xml",
    "oth": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",
    "opf": "application/oebps-package+xml",
    "qbo": "application/vnd.intu.qbo",
    "oxt": "application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension",
    "osf": "application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat",
    "weba": "audio/webm",
    "webm": "video/webm",
    "odc": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",
    "otc": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template",
    "odb": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database",
    "odf": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
    "odft": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template",
    "odg": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
    "otg": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",
    "odi": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",
    "oti": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template",
    "odp": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
    "otp": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",
    "ods": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
    "ots": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",
    "odt": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
    "odm": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
    "ott": "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",
    "ktx": "image/ktx",
    "sxc": "application/vnd.sun.xml.calc",
    "stc": "application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template",
    "sxd": "application/vnd.sun.xml.draw",
    "std": "application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template",
    "sxi": "application/vnd.sun.xml.impress",
    "sti": "application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template",
    "sxm": "application/vnd.sun.xml.math",
    "sxw": "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer",
    "sxg": "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global",
    "stw": "application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template",
    "otf": "application/x-font-otf",
    "osfpvg": "application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat.osfpvg+xml",
    "dp": "application/vnd.osgi.dp",
    "pdb": "application/vnd.palm",
    "p": "text/x-pascal",
    "paw": "application/vnd.pawaafile",
    "pclxl": "application/vnd.hp-pclxl",
    "efif": "application/vnd.picsel",
    "pcx": "image/x-pcx",
    "psd": "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop",
    "prf": "application/pics-rules",
    "pic": "image/x-pict",
    "chat": "application/x-chat",
    "p10": "application/pkcs10",
    "p12": "application/x-pkcs12",
    "p7m": "application/pkcs7-mime",
    "p7s": "application/pkcs7-signature",
    "p7r": "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp",
    "p7b": "application/x-pkcs7-certificates",
    "p8": "application/pkcs8",
    "plf": "application/vnd.pocketlearn",
    "pnm": "image/x-portable-anymap",
    "pbm": "image/x-portable-bitmap",
    "pcf": "application/x-font-pcf",
    "pfr": "application/font-tdpfr",
    "pgn": "application/x-chess-pgn",
    "pgm": "image/x-portable-graymap",
    "png": "image/x-png",
    "ppm": "image/x-portable-pixmap",
    "pskcxml": "application/pskc+xml",
    "pml": "application/vnd.ctc-posml",
    "ai": "application/postscript",
    "pfa": "application/x-font-type1",
    "pbd": "application/vnd.powerbuilder6",
    "pgp": "application/pgp-signature",
    "box": "application/vnd.previewsystems.box",
    "ptid": "application/vnd.pvi.ptid1",
    "pls": "application/pls+xml",
    "str": "application/vnd.pg.format",
    "ei6": "application/vnd.pg.osasli",
    "dsc": "text/prs.lines.tag",
    "psf": "application/x-font-linux-psf",
    "qps": "application/vnd.publishare-delta-tree",
    "wg": "application/vnd.pmi.widget",
    "qxd": "application/vnd.quark.quarkxpress",
    "esf": "application/vnd.epson.esf",
    "msf": "application/vnd.epson.msf",
    "ssf": "application/vnd.epson.ssf",
    "qam": "application/vnd.epson.quickanime",
    "qfx": "application/vnd.intu.qfx",
    "qt": "video/quicktime",
    "rar": "application/x-rar-compressed",
    "ram": "audio/x-pn-realaudio",
    "rmp": "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin",
    "rsd": "application/rsd+xml",
    "rm": "application/vnd.rn-realmedia",
    "bed": "application/vnd.realvnc.bed",
    "mxl": "application/vnd.recordare.musicxml",
    "musicxml": "application/vnd.recordare.musicxml+xml",
    "rnc": "application/relax-ng-compact-syntax",
    "rdz": "application/vnd.data-vision.rdz",
    "rdf": "application/rdf+xml",
    "rp9": "application/vnd.cloanto.rp9",
    "jisp": "application/vnd.jisp",
    "rtf": "application/rtf",
    "rtx": "text/richtext",
    "link66": "application/vnd.route66.link66+xml",
    "rss": "application/rss+xml",
    "shf": "application/shf+xml",
    "st": "application/vnd.sailingtracker.track",
    "svg": "image/svg+xml",
    "sus": "application/vnd.sus-calendar",
    "sru": "application/sru+xml",
    "setpay": "application/set-payment-initiation",
    "setreg": "application/set-registration-initiation",
    "sema": "application/vnd.sema",
    "semd": "application/vnd.semd",
    "semf": "application/vnd.semf",
    "see": "application/vnd.seemail",
    "snf": "application/x-font-snf",
    "spq": "application/scvp-vp-request",
    "spp": "application/scvp-vp-response",
    "scq": "application/scvp-cv-request",
    "scs": "application/scvp-cv-response",
    "sdp": "application/sdp",
    "etx": "text/x-setext",
    "movie": "video/x-sgi-movie",
    "ifm": "application/vnd.shana.informed.formdata",
    "itp": "application/vnd.shana.informed.formtemplate",
    "iif": "application/vnd.shana.informed.interchange",
    "ipk": "application/vnd.shana.informed.package",
    "tfi": "application/thraud+xml",
    "shar": "application/x-shar",
    "rgb": "image/x-rgb",
    "slt": "application/vnd.epson.salt",
    "aso": "application/vnd.accpac.simply.aso",
    "imp": "application/vnd.accpac.simply.imp",
    "twd": "application/vnd.simtech-mindmapper",
    "csp": "application/vnd.commonspace",
    "saf": "application/vnd.yamaha.smaf-audio",
    "mmf": "application/vnd.smaf",
    "spf": "application/vnd.yamaha.smaf-phrase",
    "teacher": "application/vnd.smart.teacher",
    "svd": "application/vnd.svd",
    "rq": "application/sparql-query",
    "srx": "application/sparql-results+xml",
    "gram": "application/srgs",
    "grxml": "application/srgs+xml",
    "ssml": "application/ssml+xml",
    "skp": "application/vnd.koan",
    "sgml": "text/sgml",
    "sdc": "application/vnd.stardivision.calc",
    "sda": "application/vnd.stardivision.draw",
    "sdd": "application/vnd.stardivision.impress",
    "smf": "application/vnd.stardivision.math",
    "sdw": "application/vnd.stardivision.writer",
    "sgl": "application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global",
    "sm": "application/vnd.stepmania.stepchart",
    "sit": "application/x-stuffit",
    "sitx": "application/x-stuffitx",
    "sdkm": "application/vnd.solent.sdkm+xml",
    "xo": "application/vnd.olpc-sugar",
    "au": "audio/basic",
    "wqd": "application/vnd.wqd",
    "sis": "application/vnd.symbian.install",
    "smi": "application/smil+xml",
    "xsm": "application/vnd.syncml+xml",
    "bdm": "application/vnd.syncml.dm+wbxml",
    "xdm": "application/vnd.syncml.dm+xml",
    "sv4cpio": "application/x-sv4cpio",
    "sv4crc": "application/x-sv4crc",
    "sbml": "application/sbml+xml",
    "tsv": "text/tab-separated-values",
    "tiff": "image/tiff",
    "tao": "application/vnd.tao.intent-module-archive",
    "tar": "application/x-tar",
    "tcl": "application/x-tcl",
    "tex": "application/x-tex",
    "tfm": "application/x-tex-tfm",
    "tei": "application/tei+xml",
    "txt": "text/plain",
    "dxp": "application/vnd.spotfire.dxp",
    "sfs": "application/vnd.spotfire.sfs",
    "tsd": "application/timestamped-data",
    "tpt": "application/vnd.trid.tpt",
    "mxs": "application/vnd.triscape.mxs",
    "t": "text/troff",
    "tra": "application/vnd.trueapp",
    "ttf": "application/x-font-ttf",
    "ttl": "text/turtle",
    "umj": "application/vnd.umajin",
    "uoml": "application/vnd.uoml+xml",
    "unityweb": "application/vnd.unity",
    "ufd": "application/vnd.ufdl",
    "uri": "text/uri-list",
    "utz": "application/vnd.uiq.theme",
    "ustar": "application/x-ustar",
    "uu": "text/x-uuencode",
    "vcs": "text/x-vcalendar",
    "vcf": "text/x-vcard",
    "vcd": "application/x-cdlink",
    "vsf": "application/vnd.vsf",
    "wrl": "model/vrml",
    "vcx": "application/vnd.vcx",
    "mts": "model/vnd.mts",
    "vtu": "model/vnd.vtu",
    "vis": "application/vnd.visionary",
    "viv": "video/vnd.vivo",
    "ccxml": "application/ccxml+xml,",
    "vxml": "application/voicexml+xml",
    "src": "application/x-wais-source",
    "wbxml": "application/vnd.wap.wbxml",
    "wbmp": "image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
    "wav": "audio/x-wav",
    "davmount": "application/davmount+xml",
    "woff": "application/x-font-woff",
    "wspolicy": "application/wspolicy+xml",
    "webp": "image/webp",
    "wtb": "application/vnd.webturbo",
    "wgt": "application/widget",
    "hlp": "application/winhlp",
    "wml": "text/vnd.wap.wml",
    "wmls": "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript",
    "wmlsc": "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc",
    "wpd": "application/vnd.wordperfect",
    "stf": "application/vnd.wt.stf",
    "wsdl": "application/wsdl+xml",
    "xbm": "image/x-xbitmap",
    "xpm": "image/x-xpixmap",
    "xwd": "image/x-xwindowdump",
    "der": "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
    "fig": "application/x-xfig",
    "xhtml": "application/xhtml+xml",
    "xml": "application/xml",
    "xdf": "application/xcap-diff+xml",
    "xenc": "application/xenc+xml",
    "xer": "application/patch-ops-error+xml",
    "rl": "application/resource-lists+xml",
    "rs": "application/rls-services+xml",
    "rld": "application/resource-lists-diff+xml",
    "xslt": "application/xslt+xml",
    "xop": "application/xop+xml",
    "xpi": "application/x-xpinstall",
    "xspf": "application/xspf+xml",
    "xul": "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml",
    "xyz": "chemical/x-xyz",
    "yaml": "text/yaml",
    "yang": "application/yang",
    "yin": "application/yin+xml",
    "zir": "application/vnd.zul",
    "zip": "application/zip",
    "zmm": "application/vnd.handheld-entertainment+xml",
    "zaz": "application/vnd.zzazz.deck+xml"
}
```

### Edit:

According to *@Octo Poulos* suggestions:

- Separated jpeg and jpg MIME into two different keys
- updated the MIME of mp4 format to `video/mp4`

Comment: There are several mistakes here, for ex "mp4" should not be "application/mp4" but "video/mp4", and MIME["jpeg"] will not work since the key is "jpeg, .jpg", same for "rss". Use at your own risk.

Comment: @OctoPoulos Thank you so much for your suggestions! As for the mp4 issue, I believe `application/mp4` is not completely wrong. It depends on the use case of the file. However, thanks to your suggestion, I have updated it to the more frequent use case, `video/mp4`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441493/7069108 for more information about its use cases.

Comment: wow can you put this in an npm package or smth?

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes Thank you for being so enthusiastic! I believe many people have maturely developed NPM packages for such things. I'm afraid I couldn't provide it as maturely as they do. But still, thank you for your support! xd

Comment: Great job friend

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively, if you're working in .NET v4.5 or above, try using [`System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping(v=vs.110).aspx)`(yourFileName)` to get MIME types. It is much better than hard-coding strings.

**UPDATE**: In .Net Core, the same can be achieved using [`FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles.fileextensioncontenttypeprovider.trygetcontenttype?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Well, considering that most apps expect to deal with just a handful of file types, I do not think using the API is _much_ better than hard-coding the strings. It's not like the MIMEs will change any time soon anyway. No need loading a truck of data into memory that you will never use.

Comment: There is no "right" answer - personally I just prefer to avoid hard-coding "magic strings" in my code and to be honest I'm too lazy to look them up each time when there's a simple method that wraps it up nicely for me.

Comment: Per the documentation current as of when I am writing this (27 Aug 2021), located at [link](https://g.nw7us.us/3ylRZty) the `MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping` only applies to **.NET Framework** 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 - so if we are in Core, we might look for another way.

Answer (score 13):

This post will explore various approaches of fetching MIME Type across various programming languages with their CONS in one-line description as header. So, use them accordingly and the one which works for you.

For eg. the code below is especially helpful when user may supply either of .xls, .xlsx or .xlsm and you don't want to write code testing extension and supplying MIME-type for each of them. Let the system do this job.

## Python 3

#### Using [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

```
>>> pip install python-magic
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file("Employee.pdf", mime=True)
'application/pdf'
```

#### Using built-in [mimeypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) module - Map filenames to MimeTypes modules

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.init()
>>> mimetypes.knownfiles
['/etc/mime.types', '/etc/httpd/mime.types', ... ]
>>> mimetypes.suffix_map['.tgz']
'.tar.gz'
>>> mimetypes.encodings_map['.gz']
'gzip'
>>> mimetypes.types_map['.tgz']
'application/x-tar-gz'
```

---

## JAVA 7

Source: [Baeldung's blog on File MIME Types in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-mime-type)

#### Operating System dependent

```
@Test
public void get_JAVA7_mimetype() {
    Path path = new File("Employee.xlsx").toPath();
    String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(path);

    assertEquals(mimeType, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

It will use FileTypeDetector implementations to probe the MIME type and invokes the probeContentType of each implementation to resolve the type. Hence, if the file is known to the implementations then the content type is returned. However, if that doesn’t happen, a system-default file type detector is invoked.

---

#### Resolve using first few characters of the input stream

```
@Test
public void getMIMEType_from_Extension(){
    File file = new File("Employee.xlsx");
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());

    assertEquals(mimeType, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

---

#### Using built-in table of MIME types

```
@Test
public void getMIMEType_UsingGetFileNameMap(){
    File file = new File("Employee.xlsx");
    FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
    String mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(file.getName());

    assertEquals(mimeType, "image/png");
}
```

It returns the matrix of MIME types used by all instances of URLConnection which then is used to resolve the input file type. However, this matrix of MIME types is very limited when it comes to URLConnection.

By default, the class uses content-types.properties file in JRE_HOME/lib. We can, however, extend it, by specifying a user-specific table using the content.types.user.table property:

```
System.setProperty("content.types.user.table","<path-to-file>");
```

---

## JavaScript

Source: [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) & [Medium's article on using Magic Numbers in JavaScript to get Mime Types](https://medium.com/the-everyday-developer/detect-file-mime-type-using-magic-numbers-and-javascript-16bc513d4e1e)

#### Interpret the Magic Number fetched using FileReader API

Final result looks something like this when one use javaScript to fetch the MimeType based on filestream. ***Open the embedded jsFiddle*** to see and understand this approach.

**Bonus**: It's accessible for most of the MIME Types and also you can add custom Mime Types in the ***getMimetype*** function. Also, it has FULL SUPPORT for MS Office Files Mime Types.

[image: FileReader API Result]

The steps to calculate mime type for a file in this example would be:

1. The user selects a file.
2. Take the first 4 bytes of the file using the
   slice method.
3. Create a new FileReader instance
4. Use the FileReader to read the 4 bytes you sliced out as an array buffer.
5. Since the array buffer is just a generic way to represent a binary buffer we need to
   create a TypedArray, in this case an Uint8Array.
6. With a TypedArray at our hands we can retrieve every byte and transform it to
   hexadecimal (by using toString(16)).
7. We now have a way to get the magic numbers from a file by reading the first four bytes. The final step is to map it to a real mime type.

**Browser Support (Above 95% overall and Close to 100% in all modern browsers)**:
[image: FileReader API]

[image: File Reader API Browser Support]

```js
const uploads = []

const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector')
fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.time('FileOpen')
  const file = event.target.files[0]

  const filereader = new FileReader()

  filereader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
      const uint = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)
      let bytes = []
      uint.forEach((byte) => {
        bytes.push(byte.toString(16))
      })
      const hex = bytes.join('').toUpperCase()

      uploads.push({
        filename: file.name,
        filetype: file.type ? file.type : 'Unknown/Extension missing',
        binaryFileType: getMimetype(hex),
        hex: hex
      })
      render()
    }

    console.timeEnd('FileOpen')
  }


  const blob = file.slice(0, 4);
  filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
})

const render = () => {
  const container = document.getElementById('files')

  const uploadedFiles = uploads.map((file) => {
    return `<div class=result><hr />
                    <span class=filename>Filename: <strong>${file.filename}</strong></span><br>
                    <span class=fileObject>File Object (Mime Type):<strong> ${file.filetype}</strong></span><br>
                    <span class=binaryObject>Binary (Mime Type):<strong> ${file.binaryFileType}</strong></span><br>
                    <span class=HexCode>Hex Code (Magic Number):<strong> <em>${file.hex}</strong></span></em>
                    </div>`
  })

  container.innerHTML = uploadedFiles.join('')
}

const getMimetype = (signature) => {
  switch (signature) {
    case '89504E47':
      return 'image/png'
    case '47494638':
      return 'image/gif'
    case '25504446':
      return 'application/pdf'
    case 'FFD8FFDB':
    case 'FFD8FFE0':
    case 'FFD8FFE1':
      return 'image/jpeg'
    case '504B0304':
      return 'application/zip'
    case '504B34':
      return 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12'
    default:
      return 'Unknown filetype'
  }
}
```

```css
.result {
  font-family: Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", "Book Antiqua", Georgia, serif;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.filename {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.fileObject {
  color: #a53;
}

.binaryObject {
  color: #63f;
}

.HexCode {
  color: #262;
}

em {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  font-style: normal;
}

input[type=file] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <input type="file" id="file-selector">

  <div id="files"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

A working method in android to populates the mapping list mime types.

```
private static void fileMimeTypeMapping() {
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("3gp", Collections.list("video/3gpp"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("7z", Collections.list("application/x-7z-compressed"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("accdb", Collections.list("application/msaccess"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ai", Collections.list("application/illustrator"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("apk", Collections.list("application/vnd.android.package-archive"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("arw", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("avi", Collections.list("video/x-msvideo"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("bash", Collections.list("text/x-shellscript"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("bat", Collections.list("application/x-msdos-program"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("blend", Collections.list("application/x-blender"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("bin", Collections.list("application/x-bin"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("bmp", Collections.list("image/bmp"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("bpg", Collections.list("image/bpg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("bz2", Collections.list("application/x-bzip2"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cb7", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cba", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cbr", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cbt", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cbtc", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cbz", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cc", Collections.list("text/x-c"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cdr", Collections.list("application/coreldraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("class", Collections.list("application/java"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cnf", Collections.list("text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("conf", Collections.list("text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cpp", Collections.list("text/x-c++src"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cr2", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("css", Collections.list("text/css"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("csv", Collections.list("text/csv"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("cvbdl", Collections.list("application/x-cbr"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("c", Collections.list("text/x-c"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("c++", Collections.list("text/x-c++src"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("dcr", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("deb", Collections.list("application/x-deb"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("dng", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("doc", Collections.list("application/msword"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("docm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("docx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("dot", Collections.list("application/msword"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("dotx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("dv", Collections.list("video/dv"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("eot", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-fontobject"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("epub", Collections.list("application/epub+zip"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("eps", Collections.list("application/postscript"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("erf", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("exe", Collections.list("application/x-ms-dos-executable"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("flac", Collections.list("audio/flac"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("flv", Collections.list("video/x-flv"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("gif", Collections.list("image/gif"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("gpx", Collections.list("application/gpx+xml"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("gz", Collections.list("application/gzip"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("gzip", Collections.list("application/gzip"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("h", Collections.list("text/x-h"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("heic", Collections.list("image/heic"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("heif", Collections.list("image/heif"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("hh", Collections.list("text/x-h"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("hpp", Collections.list("text/x-h"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("htaccess", Collections.list("text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ical", Collections.list("text/calendar"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ics", Collections.list("text/calendar"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("iiq", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("impress", Collections.list("text/impress"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("java", Collections.list("text/x-java-source"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("jp2", Collections.list("image/jp2"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("jpeg", Collections.list("image/jpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("jpg", Collections.list("image/jpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("jps", Collections.list("image/jpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("k25", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("kdc", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("key", Collections.list("application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("keynote", Collections.list("application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("kml", Collections.list("application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("kmz", Collections.list("application/vnd.google-earth.kmz"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("kra", Collections.list("application/x-krita"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ldif", Collections.list("text/x-ldif"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("love", Collections.list("application/x-love-game"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("lwp", Collections.list("application/vnd.lotus-wordpro"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m2t", Collections.list("video/mp2t"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m3u", Collections.list("audio/mpegurl"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m3u8", Collections.list("audio/mpegurl"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m4a", Collections.list("audio/mp4"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m4b", Collections.list("audio/m4b"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m4v", Collections.list("video/mp4"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("markdown", Collections.list(MIMETYPE_TEXT_MARKDOWN));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mdown", Collections.list(MIMETYPE_TEXT_MARKDOWN));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("md", Collections.list(MIMETYPE_TEXT_MARKDOWN));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mdb", Collections.list("application/msaccess"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mdwn", Collections.list(MIMETYPE_TEXT_MARKDOWN));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mkd", Collections.list(MIMETYPE_TEXT_MARKDOWN));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mef", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mkv", Collections.list("video/x-matroska"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mobi", Collections.list("application/x-mobipocket-ebook"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mov", Collections.list("video/quicktime"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mp3", Collections.list("audio/mpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mp4", Collections.list("video/mp4"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mpeg", Collections.list("video/mpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mpg", Collections.list("video/mpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mpo", Collections.list("image/jpeg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("msi", Collections.list("application/x-msi"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mts", Collections.list("video/MP2T"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("mt2s", Collections.list("video/MP2T"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("nef", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("numbers", Collections.list("application/x-iwork-numbers-sffnumbers"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("odf", Collections.list("application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("odg", Collections.list("application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("odp", Collections.list("application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ods", Collections.list("application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("odt", Collections.list("application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("oga", Collections.list("audio/ogg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ogg", Collections.list("audio/ogg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ogv", Collections.list("video/ogg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("one", Collections.list("application/msonenote"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("opus", Collections.list("audio/ogg"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("orf", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("otf", Collections.list("application/font-sfnt"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pages", Collections.list("application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pdf", Collections.list("application/pdf"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pfb", Collections.list("application/x-font"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pef", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("php", Collections.list("application/x-php"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pl", Collections.list("application/x-perl"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pls", Collections.list("audio/x-scpls"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("png", Collections.list("image/png"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pot", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("potm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("potx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ppa", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ppam", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pps", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ppsm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ppsx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ppt", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pptm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("pptx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ps", Collections.list("application/postscript"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("psd", Collections.list("application/x-photoshop"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("py", Collections.list("text/x-python"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("raf", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("rar", Collections.list("application/x-rar-compressed"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("reveal", Collections.list("text/reveal"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("rss", Collections.list("application/rss+xml"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("rtf", Collections.list("application/rtf"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("rw2", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("schema", Collections.list("text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("sgf", Collections.list("application/sgf"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("sh-lib", Collections.list("text/x-shellscript"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("sh", Collections.list("text/x-shellscript"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("srf", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("sr2", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tar", Collections.list("application/x-tar"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tar.bz2", Collections.list("application/x-bzip2"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tar.gz", Collections.list("application/x-compressed"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tbz2", Collections.list("application/x-bzip2"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tcx", Collections.list("application/vnd.garmin.tcx+xml"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tex", Collections.list("application/x-tex"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tgz", Collections.list("application/x-compressed"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tiff", Collections.list("image/tiff"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("tif", Collections.list("image/tiff"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("ttf", Collections.list("application/font-sfnt"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("txt", Collections.list("text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vcard", Collections.list("text/vcard"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vcf", Collections.list("text/vcard"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vob", Collections.list("video/dvd"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vsd", Collections.list("application/vnd.visio"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vsdm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-visio.drawing.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vsdx", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-visio.drawing"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vssm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-visio.stencil.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vssx", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-visio.stencil"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vstm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-visio.template.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("vstx", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-visio.template"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("wav", Collections.list("audio/wav"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("webm", Collections.list("video/webm"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("woff", Collections.list("application/font-woff"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("wpd", Collections.list("application/vnd.wordperfect"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("wmv", Collections.list("video/x-ms-wmv"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xcf", Collections.list("application/x-gimp"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xla", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xlam", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xls", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xlsb", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xlsm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xlsx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xlt", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xltm", Collections.list("application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xltx", Collections.list("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xrf", Collections.list("image/x-dcraw"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("yaml", Arrays.asList("application/yaml", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("yml", Arrays.asList("application/yaml", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("zip", Collections.list("application/zip"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("url", Collections.list("application/internet-shortcut"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("webloc", Collections.list("application/internet-shortcut"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("js", Arrays.asList("application/javascript", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("json", Arrays.asList("application/json", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("fb2", Arrays.asList("application/x-fictionbook+xml", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("html", Arrays.asList("text/html", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("htm", Arrays.asList("text/html", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("m", Arrays.asList("text/x-matlab", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("svg", Arrays.asList("image/svg+xml", "text/plain"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("swf", Arrays.asList("application/x-shockwave-flash", "application/octet-stream"));
     MIMETYPE_MAPPING.put("xml", Arrays.asList("application/xml", "text/plain"));

}
```

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone wants [the answer of Dirk Vollmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908) in a C# switch statement:

```c#
case "doc": return "application/msword";
case "dot": return "application/msword";
case "docx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
case "dotx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template";
case "docm": return "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12";
case "dotm": return "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12";
case "xls": return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
case "xlt": return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
case "xla": return "application/vnd.ms-excel";
case "xlsx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
case "xltx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template";
case "xlsm": return "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";
case "xltm": return "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12";
case "xlam": return "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12";
case "xlsb": return "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12";
case "ppt": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
case "pot": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
case "pps": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
case "ppa": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
case "pptx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
case "potx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template";
case "ppsx": return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow";
case "ppam": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12";
case "pptm": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12";
case "potm": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12";
case "ppsm": return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12";
case "mdb": return "application/vnd.ms-access";
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me cause my target was only Office files

Answer (score 3):

## Swift4

```
 func mimeTypeForPath(path: String) -> String {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let pathExtension = url.pathExtension

        if let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension! as NSString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() {
            if let mimetype = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() {
                return mimetype as String
            }
        }
        return "application/octet-stream"
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to import MobileCoreServices

Answer (score 3):

WPS spreadsheet :

```
application/wps-office.xlsx
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I substituted `application/wps-office.xlsx` by `application/wps-office.xltx` and it works fine, especially on Firefox . It saves me. I recommand the answer. What I can deduce is that we can substitute `.xlsx` with any office extension, and it stills work fine

Answer (score 2):

To load a .docx file:

```
    if let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "docx") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlFile)
        do{
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: url)
        }catch{
            print("errrr")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

but if you (or your client) has WPS, maybe you need add

```bash
application/wps-office.xlsx
```