# View local PDF File in ChildBrowser?

Tags: html, xcode, cordova, childbrowser

I have downloaded a PDF file to the PhoneGap LocalFileSystem and am now trying to view it in ChildBrowser. I have done so like this;

```
    function viewOffline() {
        var files = pathToRoot + "/Holidays.pdf";
        window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(files);
    }
```

When I run the app the ChildBrowser opens but it can't read the file. Is there like a .showFile thing I can use? I'm really new to ChildBrowser so any help would be much appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: is your PDF file in the www folder?

Comment: no i downloaded it from Dropbox into a folder the program automatically sends them to.

Comment: Did you try the InAppBrowser of PhoneGap? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: it's not that it doesn't work, it opens and all, i just want to know if there's a .whatever to display a local .pdfs

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick check and found out that you cannot open PDF files suing child browser. You need to use the [PDFViewer plugin](https://github.com/RandyMcMillan/CDVPDFViewer). This plugin is used only to display local PDF. When you display a PDF from an external URL, you should use InAppBrowser or ChildBrowser

Comment: ok thanks a lot. the app i'm developing also hosts .docx etc, is there another plugin for them?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896646/view-doc-docx-rtf-ppt-file-in-iphone-using-webview

Comment: This is not true, I have used ChildBrowswer many times to view PDF files.  Also, .xls, .doc and .ppt files as well.

Comment: @whodeee we are talking about local PDF files not external files.

Comment: @Whizkid747 yep I know that.  ChildBrowser CAN open the files I listed above locally, I have been doing it for a while.