# Opening .docx file in sdk 4.0

Tags: objective-c, ios4

HI i am trying to open .docx files in iPad with OS 4.0 but it is not working well it is working in OS 3.2. anybody know how to open it now in OS 4.0?
Thanx in advance

Comment: i dont know objective C, but the docx file is basically a zip file, do you have libraries to work with zips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check on the device. its a simulator bug or was for me and others..see this post: 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764709/iphone-uiwebview-loaddata-does-not-work-with-certain-types-excel-msword-ppt/3152273#3152273)