# opening docx file in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, docx

I am using the following code to open a "doc" file in objective c but if I use the same to open a docx file it is not getting opened in the simulator and it is throwing an error "EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null)". Can anyone let me know if I need to do any change to open a docx?

```
NSString *filePath = [@"/Applications/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.doc"];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 600, 1200)];
[webView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] MIMEType:@"application/msword"         textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://w.google.com"]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: So if you replace test.doc with test.docx you get the exception? Are you sure that the file exists?

Comment: yes if I replace the test.doc with test.docx I get the exception. Yes I made sure that the file exists before executing.

Comment: I think it's a bug, other people found this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work just on the simulator, it's probably a bug, see here:
[iPhone UIWebView: loadData does not work with certain types (Excel, MSWord, PPT, RTF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764709/iphone-uiwebview-loaddata-does-not-work-with-certain-types-excel-msword-ppt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuickLook framework to open the file