# Failed to display UIWebView to display docx/xlsx file with SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError error with custom URL

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

We are writing some program to display documents on iOS. I think that there are a lot of confusion on the web about what type of documents which iOS UIWebView could display.  Generally people refer to [Technical Q&A QA1630 Using UIWebView to display select document types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749) to see that all the MS office 07+ files (such as docx, xlsx, pptx) could not be displayed, however actually that is not what we see from testing. Actually we are able to display docx/xlsx/pptx document at UIWebView either loading from a remote URL, local file or in memory (loadData, here the baseURL can not be nil on simulator, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764709/iphone-uiwebview-loaddata-does-not-work-with-certain-types-excel-msword-ppt)). Of course We are testing on latest version of iOS on iPhone simulator, it might be that the support was not at older iOS. At this point, We don't know that yet. If you know, please let me know.

However right now, We have one issue to display document at UIWebView by using custom URL for security reason. I did the custom URL by following the code here: [protecting iOS resource](http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/). We could display xls, doc, ppt, pdf file, but not docx/xlsx/pptx, We got some error like this:

```
EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record
```

We tried to debug and could not figure what's to do here. Do you see similar error here? Could anyone shed some lights on this? Thanks very much.

Comment: could someone comment or give some suggestion here? I am new to iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the document you're trying to open might be corrupt. docx, xlsx, and pptx files are actually zip files containing a bunch of XML documents and other data. Check if you are able to uncompress the file on your computer by renaming it to .zip and then unzipping.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to check it. At this point, I don't think so though since for same document with same downloading code, it would work without encryption. If going through encryption, .doc would work, but not .docx, so should not be our encryption/decryption logic as well. Very weird.

Comment: turns out that there is bug at my encryption code, so the last chuck of encryption bytes are not written into final file.

Comment: got solution? I am using RNCryptor 4.0 and getting same issue.