# UIWebView using loadData compile error

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, loaddata

I have NSData in Core Data stored, could be image, rtf, video or text. I am trying to use UIWebView to show the NSData using loadData, but the build give me the error message:

> No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'loadData:MIMEType:textEncoding:baseURL:'

This is my code for RTF:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
NSData *data = entry.data;
[wv loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/rtf" textEncoding:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
[view addSubview:wv];
```

I have seen a lot of links how to use this and also Apple Documentation explains it. Why I am getting the build error? iOS Development Target is 7.0

Answer (score 0):

The comments in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764709/iphone-uiwebview-loaddata-does-not-work-with-certain-types-excel-msword-ppt?rq=1) say to not pass a nil value for the base URL. Try replacing `nil` with even just `@"https://"`

Answer (score 0):

I have restarted my MacBook and also Xcode, cleaned the project and the error is gone - very strange, but now it works fine.